# What does osascript stand for?

Tags: darwin

I am trying this command

```
osascript <<EOD
tell "Finder" something
etc
etc
```

In this command, what does the acronym osascript stand for?

Comment: it's not an acryonym. it's a program, and the of the text is used as INPUT to that program. `man osascript` or `osascript --help` will tell you what it is.

Comment: osa: Open Script Architecture.